# How to check file with given extension which are present in array list using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I want to check folder with names which are present in array and only select them which are present inside array list but with if condition
and return the value which are present inside FileArray

```
let extensionArray = [".html", ".htm", ".aspx"];
  let fileArray = [
    "index.html",
    "index.htm",
    "index.aspx",
    "Index.html",
    "Index.htm",
    "Index.aspx",
    "default.html",
    "default.htm",
    "default.aspx",
    "Default.html",
    "Default.htm",
    "Default.aspx",
  ];

if(!extensionArray.include(true){
if(!fileArray.inclue(true){
// return the output 
}
}
```

I have checked one of the post in which file can be checked from all the folder and subfolder

but I don't know where to apply my condition to check the extension and file name and then return it.

code is as follow :-

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function getFile(dir) {
  let files = await fs.readdir(dir);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) return getFile(filePath);
      else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );

  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}
```

Comment: yes @ArunKumarMohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the filenames in both capitalized and lowercase forms to `fileArray`. You can convert the filenames to lowercase when filtering them. And you can add the filenames to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Also, you don't need `extensionArray` since you're going to check for the filenames directly. Once you have the list of file paths in the directory by calling the `getFilePaths` function, you can filter them by checking if the lowercased filename (obtained by splitting the file path by `/` and getting the last element in the array) is present in the set.

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')

const filenames = new Set([
  'index.html',
  'index.htm',
  'index.aspx',
  'default.html',
  'default.htm',
  'default.aspx',
])

const getFilePaths = async (dir) => {
  let files = await fs.readdir(dir)
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(dir, file)
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath)
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return getFilePaths(filePath)
      }
      return filePath
    })
  )

  return files.flat()
}

const filterFiles = async (dir) => {
  const paths = await getFilePaths(dir)
  const filteredFiles = paths.filter((filePath) => {
    const parts = filePath.split('/')
    const filename = parts[parts.length - 1]
    return filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase())
  })
  console.log(filteredFiles)
}

filterFiles('.')
```

Comment: hey @arun how can i get all the other file (.png,.txt, .pdf) plus file which are present in filename Array (.html, .htm, .aspx) any idea ?

Comment: @Aakash You can add another condition in the callback passed to the `filter` method to check if the file extension (you can use [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path)) is present in the list.

Comment: hey @arun sorry for the trouble but can this be possible??

`let extName = [".htm",".htm,".aspx"]` 
`if(extName){
// then return fileNames Array + other extension file too
}
else{
other extension file }`

how can i get this please help

Comment: @Aakash I'm not sure if I understand. `extName` is an array and so is truthy — the `if` block will always get executed. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: i want to check all my folder with extension .html, .htm or .aspx is present or not
if files with these extension are present then i want to filter out files who's name start with index.htm, index.html and return this files along with other extension files which can be any thing it can be .png, .doc, .txt, .pdf, etc. @arun

Comment: can you help me on this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985030/return-all-the-files-with-filtered-files-using-node-js) as i am getting filterfiles and otherFIles. I dont want any html file in my OtherFiles