# return all the files with filtered files using node js

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, callback, nodes

I want to return file which are present inside folder and sub-folder but need filter on files who's extension ends with .html, .htm or .aspx

I have a code which return only files with extension `Index.html, Default.htm, Index.aspx` need rest of the files too but don't know how to return rest of the file along with this filtered extension

```
async function getAllFile(folderPath) {
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return getAllFile(filePath);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}
```

```
const filenames = new Set([
  "index.html",
  "index.htm",
  "index.aspx",
  "default.html",
  "default.htm",
  "default.aspx",
]);

const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename, parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  const filteredFiles = paths.filter((filePath) => {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    return filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase());
  });
  return filteredFiles;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filterFiles` can return an object with the `filteredFiles` and `allFiles`.

For example

```
const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename, parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  const filteredFiles = paths.filter((filePath) => {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    return filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase());
  });
  return { filteredFiles, allFiles: paths };
};
```

Or, if you need `filteredFiles`, and files that are not including on `filteredFiles`

```
const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename, parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  const filteredFiles = [];
  const otherFiles = [];
  for (const filePath of paths) {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    if (filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase())) {
      filteredFiles.push(filePath);
    } else {
      otherFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  }
  return { filteredFiles, otherFiles };
};
```

UPDATED PART BELOW

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const getAllFile = async (folderPath) => {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return await getAllFile(filePath);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
};

const filenames = new Set([
  "index.html",
  "default.htm",
  // Add your files here which you need to see in filteredFiles and don't need in otherFiles
]);

const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename, parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  const filteredFiles = [];
  const otherFiles = [];
  for (const filePath of paths) {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    if (filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase())) {
      filteredFiles.push(filePath);
    } else {
      otherFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  }
  return { filteredFiles, otherFiles };
};

filterFiles("./test")
  .then(({ filteredFiles, otherFiles }) => {
    console.log("filteredFiles:::", filteredFiles);
      console.log("otherFiles:::", otherFiles);
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log("ERRROR::", e));
```

Comment: @CyberTernal got rest of the .html .html .aspx  files too actually i dont want those file i only want .html which start with index or default

Comment: @Aakash if you need to have only .html files in `filteredFiles`, you need to update `filenames` and leave only the values which you need.

Comment: @CyberTernal i have updated `filenames` which i want but in `otherFiles` I don't need any .html .html .aspx files it should be completely filtered in `filenames`

Comment: @CyberTernal the output of `filterFiled` only include files which is mention in `filenames` and `otherfiles` does not have any .html .htm .aspx files 

Comment: issue is I am getting all other .html .htm files in `otherFiles` and i dont want any .html ,.htm files in `otherFiles` and in `filterFiles` i only want index.html, default.htm files not any abc.html or pqr.htm files its should completely filtered other .html files so my output will look like `filterfile: index.html,default.htm` and `otherFiles: abc.txt, pqr.pdf`

Comment: @Aakash please take a look at the full code snippet. I have updated the answer.