# How to filter multiple extension files using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

i want to filter out some files which are mentioned in array but don't know how to

i have seen one post but it showing only one extension how to filter it what if there is an array of extension

```
async function getAllFile(folderPath, depth) {
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return getAllFile(filePath, depth - 1);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );

  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}

const filenames = new Set([
".html",
".htm",
".aspx"
])

const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename,
    parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  
  const filteredFiles = [];
  const otherFiles = [];
  for (const filePath of paths) {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1];
    if (filenames.has(filename.toLowerCase())) {
      filteredFiles.push(filePath);
    } else {
      otherFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  }
  return { filteredFiles, otherFiles }; 
};
```

any solution how to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return all the files with filtered files using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985030/return-all-the-files-with-filtered-files-using-node-js)

Comment: no @CyberEternal

Comment: The code which you have posted here is the pretty same as in the post above, and it was my code.  Actually, I don't get the point of what you need. Can you please also post an example?  Like when and which you want to receive.

Comment: Yes its your code only but i want Output in 3 array in `FilterFiles: index.html, default.htm` in 2nd array `OtherFiles: abc.txt, pqr.pdf` but in 3rd array which is `ignoreFIles: abc.html, pqr.aspx, xyz.htm` all the .html,.htm,.aspx which is not coming inside filterFile should come in ignoreFile @CyberEternal

Comment: Please take a look at my answer @Praveen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the files that are matching the valid extensions by using `Array.filter`, `String.lastIndexOf`, `String.substr` & `Array.includes`

The below method will only return the matching extensions.

```js
let files = ["abc.txt", "/test/abc.htm", "/etc/dev/xyz.html"];

const allowedExtensions = [ ".html", ".htm", ".aspx"];

const filterFiles = (files, allowedExtns) => {
  return files.filter(file => {
  //Find the last index of '.'
    const lastIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
    //If last index of '.' is not -1 then
    //take the substring from that index till the end and 
    //check in the allowedExnts array 
    return lastIndex !== -1 && allowedExtns.includes(file.substr(lastIndex))
  })
}

console.log(filterFiles(files, allowedExtensions));
```

But, if you wish to get both the valid & invalid ones then below is the method that will be of help

```js
let files = ["abc.txt", "/test/abc.htm", "/etc/dev/xyz.html"];

const allowedExtensions = [ ".html", ".htm", ".aspx"];

const filterFiles = (files, allowedExtns) => {
  return files.reduce((acc, file) => {
    const lastIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
     //If last index of '.' is not -1 then
     //take the substring from that index till the end and 
     //check in the allowedExnts array & if the result is true
     //then add to `valid` array in the `acc` otherwise
     //add to `invalid` array in the `acc`
    if(lastIndex !== -1 && allowedExtns.includes(file.substr(lastIndex))) {
      acc.valid.push(file);
    } else{
      acc.invalid.push(file);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {valid: [], invalid: []})
}

console.log(filterFiles(files, allowedExtensions));
```

Comment: i want to ask how i will push `return file.reduce` in my else part of `OtherFiles.push`

Comment: and it showing files.reduce is not a function @Nithish

Comment: Are you passing `files` list to  `filterFiles` method?

Comment: i am passing folderPath by using postman so basically i am replacing files with folderPath @Nithish

Comment: But, the function is expecting an array with all the file names. So, you need to pass an array of file names as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const getAllFile = async (folderPath) => {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return await getAllFile(filePath);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );
  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
};

const fileExtensions = [
  ".html",
  ".htm",
  ".aspx",
  // Add your extensions here which you need to see in filteredFiles and don't need in otherFiles
];

const filenames = [
  "index",
  "default",
  // Add your fine names here which you need to see in filteredFiles
];

const filterFiles = async (folderPath) => {
  let filename, parts;
  const paths = await getAllFile(folderPath);
  const filteredFiles = [];
  const otherFiles = [];
  const ignoredFiles = [];
  for (const filePath of paths) {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    filename = parts[parts.length - 1].split(".")[0];
    let splitFileName = parts[parts.length - 1].split(".");
    if (
      fileExtensions.includes(`.${splitFileName[splitFileName.length - 1]}`)
    ) {
      if (filenames.includes(filename.toLowerCase())) {
        filteredFiles.push(filePath);
      } else {
        ignoredFiles.push(filePath);
      }
    } else {
      otherFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  }
  return { filteredFiles, otherFiles, ignoredFiles };
};

filterFiles("./test")
  .then(({ filteredFiles, otherFiles, ignoredFiles }) => {
    console.log("filteredFiles:::", filteredFiles);
    console.log("otherFiles:::", otherFiles);
    console.log("ignoredFiles:::", ignoredFiles);
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log("ERRROR::", e));
```

Comment: @Praveen it is not possible man.  Did you added the needed fine names to the `filenames`, and also needed extensions to the `fileExtensions` ?  The same file cant be added to the FilteredFiles and IgnoredFiles as they have opposite conditions

Comment: The logic is the following. If the file extension does not exist in the `fileExtensions`, the file will be pushed to the `otherFiles` list.  Otherwise,  if the file extension exits in the `fileExtensions`, and the file name exists in the `filenames` it will be pushed to the `filteredFiles `, if not exists will be pushed to the `ignoredFiles`

Comment: Great! You are welcome. Please vote for the answer as well @Praveen

Comment: is this possible to search `extName` in specific directory like `let searchDir = ["subFolder1","subfolder2"]` only when file is recursing ? if yes please help me

Comment: Everything is possible!

Comment: how @CyberEternal and is there any mail id i can contact you 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230907/discussion-between-praveen-and-cybereternal).

Comment: You need to clarify your request.  How should looks like your subdirectories, and also, what if the directory is not matched? And I think it can be another question. It is not a platform for writing code by order.